# git revert command opens a vi session for entering additional messages I need to capture that and do it through perl

Tags: git, perl

I am performing git revert , it redirects to a vi session in which I need to put in some additional information for it to submit.

Is there a way to achieve it through Perl.

Comment: The language is named "Perl", not PERL or perl. ("perl" can be used to denote the executable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git respects your `$EDITOR` environment variable when opening an editor. Set `$EDITOR` to the full path to your Perl script, which should read the name of the temporary file as its first argument.

Make sure to save your modified message back to the temporary file and exit with a 0 status.